# Does anyone know where is the Program Folder for Stepmania?

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu

I have sm-ssc 5 installed, I want to add Themes, Noteskins, Courses, Chatacter, etc. For the songs, I knew that we can put the songs in `/home/<Users>/.Stepmania 5.0` but I want to customize more to make the Stepmania fit with the Songs and Modes (such as, Dance, Beat, Pump, etc.), so Does anyone knows where is the Program Folder for Stepmania?

edit 1 : I mean data folder/obb folder/anything

Comment: Are you using 13.04 + Lubuntu? Also, how did you install StepMania - e.g. did you use the version from [here](http://www.playdeb.net/app/sm-ssc)?

Comment: yes, i got it from playdeb

Answer (score 2):

By inspecting the deb package files for [this version](http://www.playdeb.net/app/sm-ssc) from:

```
http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/pool/games/s/sm-ssc/sm-ssc-data_5.0~beta3-1~getdeb1_all.deb
http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/pool/games/s/sm-ssc/sm-ssc_5.0~beta3-1~getdeb1_i386.deb
```

This is likely the folder you need:

```
/usr/share/games/sm-ssc
```

If its not this version, it could be in `/usr/share`, `/usr/share/games`, etc.